# Return statement after throwing an exception in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

The following function from Systems.Collections.Generic.Dictionary class has return statement after throwing an exception, does any one have any idea why?

```
    public TValue this[TKey key] {
        get { 
            int i = FindEntry(key);
            if (i >= 0) return entries[i].value;
            ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException();
            **return default(TValue);** 
        }
        set { 
            Insert(key, value, false); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Covered by Eric Lippert just recently: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/24/never-say-never-part-two.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though the

```
ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException();
```

Certainly does throw an exception, the compiler is not sophisticated enough to prove that it will *never* do anything else.  And since it cannot *prove* that the function never returns, it has to assume that it *could* return.

Eric Lippert just finished a mini-series on his blog entitled "Never Say Never" about this very issue.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/21/never-say-never-part-one.aspx

It turns out that this is a simple case of the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), which has been shown to be undecidable over Turing Machines.

Comment: Just like when you add a return statement in the try{} block, the compiler assumes that there is no return from the method and raises the compile time errors. I think complier should be able to figure out there is an throwhelper (derived from base class Exception) and raise the same compilation errors ?

Answer (score 3):

It is forced to, because the method itself is not directly throwing, the ThrowHelper is. The compiler has no way of knowing this, so to satisfy the compiler the `return default(TValue);` is added, even though it will never get invoked.